# Переход на другую строчку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы я переходил на другую строчку?

```
os.system('cls||clear') # очищаем экран 
    back = (colored ("0 = назад ---> " , 'red'))
    print (colored ("---------------SCANER---------------" , 'red')) #приветствие :)
    print (colored ("[1]=сканировать отдельный порт" , 'yellow'))
    print (colored ("[2]=сканировать список" , 'yellow'))
    print (colored ("[3]=о самом скрипте" , 'yellow'))
    x = int(input(colored("[scan] ---> " , 'white')))
    if x==1:
        f1()
    elif x==2:
        f2()
    elif x==3:
        os.system('cls||clear') 
        print (colored ("О скрипте и что он делает: Данный скрипт сканирует порты у хоста и проверят их закрыты они или нет." , 'blue'))
        print (colored ("1 функция скрипта сканирует конкретный порт выбранный вами." , 'blue'))
        print (colored ("2 функция скрипта сканирует несколько портов. есть два варианта:" , 'blue'))
        print (colored ("2.1 сканирует самые известный порты. 2.2 сканирует все порты от 1 до 6535" , 'blue'))
        print (colored ("Примечание: Будьте остарожнее с функцией 2.2! у вас может зависнуть компьютер или быть проблемы с провайдером!!!" , 'blue'))
        print (colored ("by Bogdan" , 'blue'))
    


    else:   
        print (colored("Ошибка!" , 'red'))
```

перед else нужно что бы программа задавала вопрос хотите ли вы вернуться назад? тогда мы вводим число и он возращает нас на первую строчку (сорри за глупый вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходим бесконечный цикл с выходом по условию:

```
while True:
  # ваш код который вы привели в вопросе
  r = int(input(colored("Repeat? 0 - No, 1 - Yes " , 'white')))
  if r==0:
    break
```